# Connect to a bluetooth device, exception: Service discovery failed

Tags: android

Iam trying to connect my android device with a bluetooth compatible device. I know the mac-address of this device, as you can see in my code below. I also made several `Toasts` just to verify the steps in the code. It seems that I manage to create `tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);` I assume this because the Toast raises a message saying some bluetooth object address, in this line of code:

```
String test = tmp.toString(); 
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The bluetooth socket: " +test, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But the code failes semantically when I do a `tmp.connect();` I am working on API level 15, android 4.0

This i my piece of code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;  
import java.util.UUID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SimpleConnectAndroidActivity extends Activity {

final static String toast = "IAM HERE"; 

final static String TAG ="SimpleConnect";
UUID MY_UUID;

BluetoothDevice bd;
BluetoothAdapter ba;

Button connectButton;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    ba = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    connectButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    connectButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            boolean b = ba.checkBluetoothAddress("00:1B:DC:0F:EC:7E");
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null; 

            //If valid bluetoothAddress
            if(b) {
                final BluetoothDevice device = ba.getRemoteDevice("00:1B:DC:0F:EC:7E"); //Getting the Verifier Bluetooth 

                //Trying to create a RFCOMM socket to the device
                try {
                    tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }

                try {
                    tmp.connect();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No connection was made! Exception: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } 
                //Print out the sockets name
                String test = tmp.toString(); 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The bluetooth socket: " +test, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            }


            else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FALSE, No bluetooth device with this address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }   
    });  
}
```

}

I am aware of that this should be done in a separate thread, and yes, I read the Bluetooth Chat example provided by Google.

Can someone help me out?

**EDIT**

This is the only thing I got from LogCat:

```
07-06 10:10:22.085: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(14019): ...fd 63 created (RFCOMM, lm = 26)
```

**EDIT 2**

Ok, now got a new error, but its a better error. When i press the connect button, the phone asks for the pin code for pair the devices, but its already paired! After I paired it for the second time, the error says: Connection refused and another exception says, timeout.

Comment: Please add some logcat prints too.

Comment: You need Client Server communication?

Comment: My phone should act as a server, for listing to incoming data. I have no options for connection to the phone on the remote device, so i assume that this should be done in the android app. The device supports RFCOMM as a service and uses OBEX for file transfer.

Comment: Service Discovery failed means that the device you are trying to connect is not in Discoverable mode or not able to found

Comment: Venky: It doesn't matter if the remote device is discoverable or not, if I know the mac-address? The remote device also saying that its paired with my phone.

Comment: After paring you got this error?

Comment: I'am not trying to pair the device inside my app, this should just be done in the settings of my android phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this code:`Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
mySocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);`

Comment: I thought this was for android 2.x ?

Comment: oh,sorry,you can try this one :tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);socket = tmp.accept();manageConnectedSocket(socket);

Comment: Try what? Did you miss the url? ;)

Comment: The documentation says that: Use createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID) to connect to this socket from another device using the same UUID. I can't do any thing with the software on my remote device.

Comment: your remote device is a client or server side？If you can,i can send a  email to you .

Comment: Can you? you can find my email at my profile. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: i'm sorry ,i didn't find your email,but this url could help you.                        http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html.There are some examples .